# No se encuentra modulo xmlbuilder cuando estoy instalando ionic'

Tags: nodejs

No puedo corregir este error. Alguien me puede decir por qué?
Gracias.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:12:13)
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:436:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Comment: Hi Franciso, this is Stack Overflow en español. Please translate your question or ask it in the english version, otherwise it might be migrated or closed

Comment: Perdon. Estoy comenzando con ionic, y cuando lo instalo me devuelve el error que adjunte arriba. No se como resolverlo.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y de paso agregarle mas detalles del problema y así otros podrán contestarla

Comment: Deberías editar el título de la pregunta a algo como 'No se encuentra modulo xmlbuilder cuando estoy instalando ionic', ademas de dar más detalles para poder reproducirlo y ayudarte a solucionarlo.

Comment: gracias, ahora corrijo

Answer (score 1):

El módulo que indicas parece ser de Apache Cordova, comentas que eres nuevo usando `ionic`,

te recomiendo instales Apache Cordova

```
>npm install -g cordova
```